# How do I use items in a listbox that are gathered from a database to select an item in the database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, select, listbox

Okay, now this would be normally easy for me but there's one little block that's making it so that I can't figure it out. The best way to do this is to show you the code that I have then explain further what I'm trying to do.

P.S. This is an address book program that i'm just creating for fun.

The actual question is at the bottom if you just want to skip to that.

Here is the connection to my **Access** Database:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Database_Connection

    Public provider As String
    Public datafile As String
    Public connstring As String
    Public myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader

    Public Sub Access_Database()

        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        datafile = "AddressBook.accdb"
        connstring = provider & datafile
        myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring

        Try
            myconnection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Original Error: " & ex.ToString)
        Finally
            myconnection.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub


    End Module
```

Screenshot of database:
[image: Database]

Screenshot of Form:
[image: Main Form]

Now, on the form's load, it takes the information from the database (The names) and fills the Listbox with them

It fills it with both the first name and last name because it needs to display that.
Here is the code that does that on the form load:

```
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Access_Database()

    Try
        myconnection.Open()

        Dim str As String

        str = "SELECT * FROM Contacts"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read

            Nameslst.Items.Add(dr("FullName").ToString)

        End While

        Nameslst.Sorted = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        myconnection.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

**ACTUAL QUESTION HERE:**

Now, how do I set whatever they actually select in the listbox to select that data in the database? I would use a Select Case statement but that's to specific the listbox could fill infinitively and a new case would have to be entered into the code for every person added.

I don't know how to go about this please help! Thanks in advance for all responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add an handler for the [Listbox.SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx).
Whenever you receive this event, extract the FullName from the current selected item and use the string to query the database. After getting the results you update your textbox accordingly

```
Private Sub listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

   if listBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        return
   End If

   Dim curName As String = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
   Try

       myconnection.Open()

       Dim str = "SELECT * FROM Contacts Where FullName=?"
       Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", curName)
       Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
       While dr.Read
           txtBoxFirstName.Text = dr("FirstName").ToString()
           .....
           ... and so on for the other fields
       End While
  Catch(ex as Exception)
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
  Finally
       myConnection.Close()
  End Try

End Sub
```

Of course this is pseudocode, more work is required to get to a functionally stable application.
For example you will need to check for [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.isdbnull.aspx) when you read back data from the db.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson sure in a real world app you should handle homonyms, but I think that this is just good exercise without too much complexity.

Comment: Dunno habits learned early are hard to break. Mind you I never mentioned doing an ORM and some DI for unit testing...

Comment: I have no unique columns. It work until the dbnull comes into play.

Would this be what you're talking about with the DBnull?

                `If dr("FirstName") = IsDBNull(True) Then

                Else
                    FirstNamelbl.Text = dr("FirstName")
                End If`

Comment: `FirstNameLbl.Text  = if(dr.IsDbNull(dr.GetOrdinal("FirstName")), "---", dr("FirstName))` but also yours is fine

Comment: Acutally, yours works, mine doesn't lol, i don't understand why, but i'm going to try to figure it out. THanks again Steve. Once again, you come to my rescue xD

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of doing this. Here's one
Create a struct/class with say
ContactID, FullName

override ToString(), to return FullName
In your while loop filling in the listbox first create an instance (Contact?) fill in ID, and FullName, then add that to the list.

Then when the user selects an item out of the listbox in the event handler cast
ListBox.Selected to the type of your Struct/class, get the ID property
then pass it as parameter to in something like 'Select * From Contacts Where ContactID =?'
Use the result from that query to fill in the right hand side

Another option you might want to consider.
Is defining a contact class, and a ContactList, and filling it with another method that does the db stuff. 
At the moment your form is doing everything. If you wanted an other one with contacts, perhaps a tree showing which of your contacts had contacts, you would be duplicating a lot of code.

Comment: I will most likely use a method to get the information passed through, I'm only trying to get the  basic functionality of it working right now. Thanks for your input! :)